IQ puzzle with diagonal lines in boxes
Please solve this puzzle for me. Source: https://www.treningmozga.com/en/iq/iq-test-46/iq-test.php?qu=22&an=6&ot=18


Probably just the fourth option because it is the only one with three diagonal dashes per tile from top right to bottom left…

True option is the fourth. I thought so much. It turned out problem is very easy :)))

@tuấnlê If that's the answer, you're welcome to post it as an answer, along with an explanation.

Answer is the fourth because  it is the only one with three diagonal dashes per tile from top right to bottom left
